# Pandas rolling mean calculation when dataframe has multiple indices

Tags: pandas

I wish to create a pandas rolling mean for 2 periods. But my problem is that within each period I have a category and I want to create a separate mean for each category.
i.e

```
Period  AcctStatus  ACTBalance
31/01/2017  Active           100
            Default          200
28/02/2017  Active           300
            Default          240
31/03/2017  Active           450
            Default          300
30/04/2017  Active           150
            Default          100
31/05/2017  Active           150
            Default          500
```

The first 2 fields are my indices.
I want a 2 period rolling mean but if I just use :

```
df['ACTBalance'].rolling(2).mean()
```

It just computes the average of the 2 adjacent values. So for 31/05/2017, for Default, it will compute: (500+150)/2, but what I want is: (500+100)/2
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `groupby` here

```
df.groupby(level=1).ACTBalance.apply(lambda x : x.rolling(2).mean())
Out[96]: 
Period      AcctStatus
31/01/2017  Active          NaN
            Default         NaN
28/02/2017  Active        200.0
            Default       220.0
31/03/2017  Active        375.0
            Default       270.0
30/04/2017  Active        300.0
            Default       200.0
31/05/2017  Active        150.0
            Default       300.0
Name: ACTBalance, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, does the level=1 refer to the ActStatus or the Period?

Comment: @Victor refer to the AcctStatus

Comment: Thanks, it seems the new column is also called ActBalance? IS it possible to dynamically assign a diferet name to it? like MA_2PRD

Comment: `p=2`;
`df['MA_{}PRD'.format(p)]=df.groupby(level=1).ACTBalance.apply(lambda x : x.rolling(p).mean())` @Victor you can try this :-)